# Create video from screen grabs in android

Tags: android, video

I would like to record user interaction in a video that people can then upload to their social media sites.

For example, the Talking Tom Cat android app has a little camcorder icon.  The user can press the camcorder icon, then interact with the app, press the icon to stop the recording and then the video is processed/converted ready for upload.

I think I can use setDrawingCacheEnabled(true) to save images but don't know how to add audio or make a video.

**Update:** After further reading I think I will need to use the NDK and ffmpeg.  I prefer not to do this, but, if there are no other options, does anyone know how to do this?

Does anyone know how to do this in Android?

### Relevant links...

[Android Screen capturing or make video from images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091794/android-screen-capturing-or-make-video-from-images)

[how to record screen video as like Talking Tomcat application does in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980370/how-to-record-screen-video-as-like-talking-tomcat-application-does-in-iphone)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) API with `CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE` to set it up as an encoder.  No ffmpeg required :)

You've already found how to grab the screen in the other question you linked to, now you just need to feed each captured frame to `MediaCodec`, setting the appropriate format flags, timestamp, etc.

**EDIT:** Sample code for this was hard to find, but [here it is](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/6289d680cb75fa5a985464b9f362d4a2a007a7bf%5E!/#F0), hat tip to Martin Storsjö.    Quick API walkthrough:

```
MediaFormat inputFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", width, height);
inputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitRate);
inputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, frameRate);
inputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, colorFormat);
inputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 75);
inputFormat.setInteger("stride", stride);
inputFormat.setInteger("slice-height", sliceHeight);

encoder = MediaCodec.createByCodecName("OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.H264E"); // need to find name in media codec list, it is chipset-specific

encoder.configure(inputFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
encoder.start();
encoderInputBuffers = encoder.getInputBuffers();
encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();

byte[] inputFrame = new byte[frameSize];

while ( ... have data ... ) {
    int inputBufIndex = encoder.dequeueInputBuffer(timeout);

    if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer inputBuf = encoderInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];
        inputBuf.clear();

        // HERE: fill in input frame in correct color format, taking strides into account
        // This is an example for I420
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                inputFrame[ i * stride + j ] = ...; // Y[i][j]
                inputFrame[ i * stride/2 + j/2 + stride * sliceHeight ] = ...; // U[i][j]
                inputFrame[ i * stride/2 + j/2 + stride * sliceHeight * 5/4 ] = ...; // V[i][j]
            }
        }

        inputBuf.put(inputFrame);

        encoder.queueInputBuffer(
            inputBufIndex,
            0 /* offset */,
            sampleSize,
            presentationTimeUs,
            0);
    }

    int outputBufIndex = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, timeout);

    if (outputBufIndex >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer outputBuf = encoderOutputBuffers[outputBufIndex];

        // HERE: read get the encoded data

        encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(
            outputBufIndex, 
            false);
    }
    else {
        // Handle change of buffers, format, etc
    }
}
```

There are also some [open issues](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37769).

**EDIT:** You'd feed the data in as a byte buffer in one of the supported pixel formats, for example I420 or NV12.  There is unfortunately no perfect way of determining which formats would work on a particular device; however it is typical for the same formats you can get from the camera to work with the encoder.

Comment: Hi been researching a bit but there aren'tmany examples out there.. how would I actually feed each captured frame into MediaCodec?

Comment: Hi Alex,  Thanks for all the code.  Say I had a series of images, say image01.png, image02.png,... etc, each of these would be assigned to the variable "inputFrame" and  then eventually put into the ByteBuffer variable "inputBuf"?

Comment: @Mel: Yes, but the images need to be converted to an array of pixels in the right colorspace, you can't just assign them to inputFrame without a conversion.  I showed above how to pack arrays of pixels in Y,U,V colorspace into an inputFrame; to go from a png you need to (a) decode the png to an array of RGB pixels, and (b) convert each pixel from RGB to YUV; then pack as shown above.

Comment: Is there any way to do the same on android?